# AngularJS ng-repeat with custom element inside a table is rendering strangely

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to re-use a portion of my HTML view in multiple places.  The portion I want to re-use is table cells in an HTML table.  The problem is that my custom directive inside a ng-repeat is doing funny things.  I have reproduced the problem on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ravishi/BA4tQ/).  There are two HTML tables in the jsFiddle.  The first is ng-repeat with the table cells written in the view and the second is the table cells coming from a directive, my-element.  Chrome dev tools report that the rendered HTML looks like this.  Note that the custom element appears only once and is outside the table.

Rendered HTML

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl" class="ng-scope">
    table1
    <table class="table table-hover">
      <tbody><!-- ngRepeat: p in people -->
          <tr ng-repeat="p in people" class="ng-scope">
            <td class="ng-binding">Name: Mike</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">Age: 20</td>
          </tr>
          <tr ng-repeat="p in people" class="ng-scope">
            <td class="ng-binding">Name: Peter S</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">Age: 22</td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <br>table2
    <my-element class="ng-binding">Name: Age: </my-element>
    <table class="table table-hover">
      <tbody>
        <!-- ngRepeat: p in people -->
        <tr ng-repeat="p in people" class="ng-scope">
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="p in people" class="ng-scope">    
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Source HTML

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    table1
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <tr ng-repeat="p in people">
            <td>Name: {{ p.name }}</td>
            <td>Age: {{ p.age }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br/>table2
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <tr ng-repeat="p in people">
            <my-element></my-element>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Source JS

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.directive('myElement', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<td>Name: {{ p.name }}</td><td>Age: {{ p.age }}</td>'
    }
});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.people = [{
        name: 'Mike',
        age: 20
    }, {
        name: 'Peter S',
        age: 22
    }];
}
```

Please note the jsFiddle is a trivial example and common sense would lead to just not using directives at all.  However, my target code has a much larger template that I want to re-use.  I've tried using "ng-include" as well but the result is similar.

Comment: The reason for this to happen is the "Adoption Agency Algorithm" which is part of your browser. When checking the DOM, my-element is moved outside the table element, because a tr element is expected.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

`<td>` is known to behave strangely in directives like this. Instead, use a directive on the parent `<tr>`. Read more about this issue here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1459

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="p in people" my-element></tr>
</table>
```

Here is how you can further improve your directive so that it is more re-usable.

```
app.directive('myElement', function () {
  return {
    scope: {
      item: '=myElement'
    },
    restrict: 'EA',
    template: '<td>Name: {{item.name}}</td><td>Age: {{item.age}}</td>'
    };
});
```

and pass in the value of `item` like so:

```
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="person in people" my-element="person"></tr>
  </table>
```

### [Live Demo](http://jsbin.com/gopula/1/edit)

Comment: Both m59 and @sza answers worked but I appreciated the additional comments about code improvements.

Comment: What is so special about this solution then?

Comment: Apologies. The naming made your intent unclear. I thought you were doing something else.

Comment: this works, but the rendered html loses the internal td tags. e.g. <td my-element="" class="ng-binding">Name: MikeAge: 20</td> with nothing between Mike & Age. Any idea why?

Comment: This seems to work, but as @ade jones pointed out, it actually fails. should either follow zsong's answer or use 'replace: true'. Further information about 'replace: true': https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1459

Comment: @gfaceless ah yeah, that was a mess. I didn't notice what I had done there. I corrected everything. I was new to Angular back then.

Comment: is there a way to access $index in the template?

Comment: @ChrisHayes Sure, pass it in on the scope. `index="$index"` `scope: {index: '=', `

Answer (score 13):

Apply the directive to `<tr>` like this:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <tr my-element blah='p' ng-repeat="p in people"></tr>
</table>

app.directive('myElement', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope:{
            ngModel: '=blah'
        },
        template: '<td>Name: {{ ngModel.name }}</td><td>Age: {{ ngModel.age }}</td>'
    }
});
```

<kbd>**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/U32m6/)**</kbd>

Comment: I'd avoid this - re-using ng-model seems to unnecessarily confuse things with the normal use of ng-model and bindings with forms, etc.

Comment: @TheBigC I think I'd better rename it to something else. Thx.

Comment: @TheBigC This one should not matter at all.

Answer (score 3):

Use `replace: true` in your directive and your `<my-element>` will be replaced with the root item in your template, a `<td>`, so this will not confuse the HTML.

Comment: with the current template this would result in an *Template must have exactly one root element.* error.

Comment: Ah, yes of course.  Maybe wrap in a `<tbody>` if that works within the context of a <tr>.. otherwise see m59's answer.

Comment: Good idea, but seems to throw that template error no matter what. Not sure how to fix that.