# AngularJS : directive template scope inheritance

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

What is the correct way to pass scope vars to directive templates using ng-repeat? I'm trying to iterate over an array of data to render some "app" elements which contain templateUrls. If I don't set scope : true in the directive the template vars are empty. What is the correct way to pass the vars defined in ng-repeat to the template without polluting the scope?

```
// controller
userApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope', 'mainFactory', 'credsFactory',
function($scope, mainFactory, credsFactory) {

    var findAppsData = function() {

        mainFactory.findAppsData()
            .success(function (data) {
                $scope.appsData = data;
            }).
            error(function(error) {
                $scope.status = 'Unable to get data: ' + error.message;
            });
    };  

    findAppsData();

}]);


// directive
userApp.directive('app', function(){
    return {
        restrict : "E",
        scope : {}, // vars referenced in template are empty.
        scope : true // vars are inherited in template.
        templateUrl : 'templates/app-detail.html'
    }
})

// index.html
<app ng-repeat="app in appsData"></app>

// app-detail.html
<span class="rtl">{{ app.appDisplayName }}</span>
<span class="rtl">&nbsp;|&nbsp;{{ app.categoryId }}</span>
<br />
<span class="rtl">{{ app.description }}</span>
```

Comment: This answer worked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18600710/angularjs-ng-repeat-with-custom-element-inside-a-table-is-rendering-strangely

Answer (score 0):

Working solution: http://plnkr.co/edit/QfTQao?p=preview

You'll need to use the link function to wait for the variables to get passed in when they compile, and the compile the view then.

Try something like this:

```
// directive
userApp.directive('app', function($compile){
    return {
        // staying away from E, IE doesn't like custom elements
        restrict : "A",
        scope : {
          app: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {          
          var delWatch = scope.$watch('app', function(newVal, oldVal) {

            // wait for scope.app to load
            if(scope.app === undefined) return;

            var template = '';
            template += '<span class="rtl">{{ app.appDisplayName }}</span>';
            template += '<span class="rtl">&nbsp;|&nbsp;{{ app.categoryId }}</span>';
            template += '<br />';
            template += '<span class="rtl">{{ app.description }}</span>';

            element.html(template);
            $compile(element.contents())(scope);

            // remove watcher
            delWatch();
          }); 
        }
    }
});

// index.html
<div ng-repeat="app in appsData">
  <div app="app"></div>
</div>
```