# AngularJS dynamic ng-repeat directive, the html not redering

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

here is demo: http://codepen.io/mafeifan/pen/PzrGRE?editors=1010

table1 is working,
in table2 I wrote a directive to render the td , but not work. I don't know why.

Html：

```
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="tr in vm.getTrs() track by $index">
        <form-cell ng-repeat="cell in vm.getCellsByRow($index+1)">data</form-cell>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

JS：

```
App.directive('formCell', function(){
  return {
    replace: true,
    template: '<td>td</td>'
  }
```

});

if I change to

```
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="tr in vm.getTrs() track by $index">
        <td ng-repeat="cell in vm.getCellsByRow($index+1)"><form-cell></form-cell></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

JS:

```
change the template to '<span>td</td>' in directive
```

it's working, I don't know why

Comment: `form-cell` is not a valid html tag.
Also you do need a `td` or `th` in a `tr`

Comment: You can take a look at this post: [AngularJS ng-repeat with custom element inside a table is rendering strangely](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18600710/angularjs-ng-repeat-with-custom-element-inside-a-table-is-rendering-strangely).

Answer (score 0):

You do need `<th>` or `<td>` in `<tr>` tags:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <table border="1">
         <tr>
            <td>renders</td>
            <td>renders</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <div>renders outside the table</div>
            <td>renders</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems `form-cell` tag is not allowed inside `tr` tag and browser may do something wrong. Use the directive inside an attribute:

```
App.directive('formCell', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A', // <-- add the restriction
    replace: true,
    template: '<td>td</td>'
  }
});
```

Like:

```
<td form-cell ng-repeat="cell in vm.getCellsByRow($index+1)">data</td>
```